# React-Native physical device not connecting to server

Tags: android, react-native, ubuntu

Here's whats happening-
react-native run-android fails giving the following error message-
"
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

"

Here's a list of things i have done-

1. Connected my phone (Redmi Note 7 pro) to the laptop (uses ubuntu 18.04) using a usb cable. And followed all instructions from the react-native documentation (USB debugging etc) but the device (phone) doesnt show on using the command `adb devices` . I have also tried connecting the phone as a file transfer device and every other mode possible.
2. I have tried connecting via the wifi network (which works) but the last time i did it i had to turn off MIUI optimisation, and this led to whatsapp going haywire and i had to reinstall whatsapp. From what i know this is a necessary condition, if wireless connection is to be made to an MI phone.
3. Android emulator..... simply doesnt work (i have tried many SO tricks, none worked).

So is there a way to solve these issues? or is there any other method using which i can run my react-native application for debugging.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that Developer mode is enabled with USB debugging in the device. If USB debugging is enabled then the device id should be listed in the `adb devices` list. If not then try to add ADB driver for the device or a universal ADB driver.